# Calculate intersection of points on graph

Tags: math, svg

I'm trying to generate SVG paths that repeat. To do this I am plotting a minimum of 2 points on a graph to create a line like so...

[image]

However I want to draw a straight line from the last point to the next point of the repeated path on the next SVG, and to do that I need to find the `Y` position where the current graph ends and the next starts.

[image]

Based on the x and y coordinates of the 2 points, how do I calculate the y coordinate (that's in red and should be 40 in this example)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the tile size is `a x a`, you can construct a coordination system from the bottom left of the first tile. Also assume the finish of the first line is `(x1,y1)` and in this new coordination system, the start of the second line would be `(a+x2,y2)`. Look at the following paint masterpiece (:D) to understand what I mean.
[image]
OK, now you can write the line's formula of these two points:

```
y-y1=((y2-y1)/(a+x2-x1))(x-x1)
```

replacing `x` with `a` and solving the formula for `y` would result in what you need:

```
y=((y2-y1)/(a+x2-x1))(a-x1)+y1
```

**UPDATE**

From the values you represented, you can use the formula by replacing `x1=70, x2=20, y1=100, y2=0, a=100`

Comment: Hey @Sinapse thanks so much for you answer. I'm a little confused after trying your formula, but that's probably down to my terrible math knowledge and my confusing question. Each graph is separate, so for both graphs the coordinates are identical: eg in this case point one is `{ x: 20, y: 0 }` point two is `{x: 70, y: 100 }`

Comment: Thanks for the update @Sinapse. I'm close(ish), but based on this calculation `((100 - 0) / (100+70-20))(100-20)+0` i'm getting `53.33` but I'm expecting `40`

Comment: OK, you are assuming the first point to be what should be the second in the above formulation. Just swap `x1` by `x2` and `y1` by `y2`. Answer has been updated, try the new values and you will get 40

Comment: thanks so much. Works a charm! I seriously owe you a beer!

Comment: One final question. Apart from getting a degree in Math, any idea where a good resource is to learn this sort of stuff? I had a Google earlier to try and figure this out, and it was quite overwhelming!

Comment: @DanV of course you could not find anything by searching in google because the nature of math is abstraction and you can search the terms of abstraction to get any result. For a problem to be solved, it requires first, modeling your problem which is more an art than science (e.g. sticking those two tiles and building a coordination system based on the first one is modeling). And second you need techniques to solve the problem (e.g. writing the lines formula and solving it for `y`).

Comment: These two should be exercised so that in face of a new problem you can solve it with the experience you gained. Generally these kinds of problems like the one you faced, is in the field of `Analytic geometry` you can search for it, and find some good materials if you want to improve your math skills in these kinds of problems